# Fullscreen DialogFragment with softInputMode adjustResize

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

So I have a DialogFragment that i expand to the whole screen in onResume with the following code:

```
    val params = dialog?.window?.attributes
    params?.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    params?.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    dialog?.window?.attributes = params as WindowManager.LayoutParams
```

I also use the following style:

```
<style name="AppTheme.FullscreenDialogFragment" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background1</item>
</style>
```

Now I also want this to extend under the status bar and I do this via the following (I also set the status bar color to transparent):

```
dialog?.window?.decorView?.systemUiVisibility =
    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE.addFlag(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN)
```

This all works completely fine, but now I want to adjust the softInputMode to adjustResize. And I just can't get it to work. It only works if I remove the Layout flags above. It works fine in normal fragments. Does anybody have an idea what I'm missing here or is it just not possible with a DialogFragment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my problem was not the DialogFragment but the fact that Android does not honor adjustResize when you make your layout draw under the system bars. To prevent this you need to listen to the Window insets and apply them as padding to your layout so that when the keyboard is open, the bottom inset makes your whole content smaller for that amount and the ScrollView can be scrolled to the bottom. I use the following library for insets:

https://github.com/chrisbanes/insetter